# oracle range partition on timestampe column

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

This is what I have written to create a table with a daily partition on the createTime field

```
create table T_ASYNCFCMNOTIFICATION (
    C_ID NUMBER(34, 0) not null,
    C_CREATETIME timestamp not null,
    C_DEVICETOKEN varchar2(255 char),
    F_DATA NUMBER(34, 0),
    primary key (C_ID)
)
   PARTITION BY RANGE (C_CREATETIME)
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'day'))
(
 PARTITION T_ASYNCFCMNOTIFICATION_P1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-11-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
 );
```

but when I run my query I've got this error :

Error report -
ORA-14752: Interval expression is not a constant of the correct type
14752. 00000 -  "Interval expression is not a constant of the correct type"
*Cause:    You attempted to use either a nonconstant interval or an interval
whose data type does not correspond to the partitioning column
*Action:   Use only constant expressions for the interval. If the data type of
partitioning column is numeric, the interval must be a numeric
constant. If the data type is of type date/time, the interval must
be a constant of interval type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use interval `NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'day')` for a *daily* partitioning

this works fine

```
....
PARTITION BY RANGE (C_CREATETIME)
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'day'))
(
 PARTITION T_ASYNCFCMNOTIFICATION_P1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-11-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
 );
```

Interval [NUMTOYMINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions104.htm) is used for `YEAR` or `MONTH`-ly partitioning